Searchform closes when click outside
I want, when my Searchform is active it creates an overlay for the background and when I click outside the Searchform (on the overlay), the Searchform should close and the overlay should disappear too.
<form method="get" id="searchform" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_attr( home_url() ); ?>" _lpchecked="1">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="search" name="s" id="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Search the site', 'sociallyviral' ); ?>" <?php if (!empty($mts_options['mts_ajax_search'])) echo ' autocomplete="off" '; ?> />
        <button id="search-image" class="sbutton" type="submit" value="">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

My Overlay CSS will be like this-
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    background: rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
    z-index: 1;

enter image description here
The result should be like this. Whenever the Searchform is active, it creates a overlay in the background (Only Searchform will be outside the overlay) and whenever I click outside the Searchform or on the overlay, the searchform closes and overlay disappears too.

First let's add a div to be our overlay:
<div id="overlay"></div>

Now let's add some styles for the overlay and the form:
#searchform {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
}

#searchform fieldset {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  border: none;
}

#searchform fieldset input {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#search-image {
  border: none;
  background: #f47555;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 60%);
  z-index: 1;
}

With this style, the form and the overlay should already be appearing correctly, now we just need to do the interaction part, that's the job of JS:
const searchForm = document.getElementById("searchform");
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

function toggleSearchForm(show = null) {
  const formIsVisible =
    show !== null ? !show : searchForm.style.display === "none";
  searchForm.style.display = formIsVisible ? "none" : "block";
  overlay.style.display = formIsVisible ? "none" : "block";
}

overlay.addEventListener("click", () => toggleSearchForm(false));

In this code we first select the HTML elements we'll need:

searchForm
overlay

Then I have a function to toggle the visibility of the form and the overlay, in this function you can define whether you want to display it or not or you can simply toggle it based on the current state.
Further down in the code I add the overlay click event listener so that when it is clicked it executes the toggleSearchForm function to hide the form and overlay.
